# Yii2 Console Controller Errors

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pheanstalk

I created a console controller named beanstalk, this is my first time using the console controllers, am trying to run it from the terminal and i got these errors

```
Error: Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::user
Error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/apc.so'...
```

The Controller

```
class BeanstalkController extends \yii\console\Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    echo 'test console controller';
} }
```

and i am calling it using

```
php yii beanstalk
```

i also tried other actions names with no luck

here is my console config

```
return [
'id' => 'app-console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
'modules' => [],
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ]
],
'params' => $params,
```

];

can anyone help?

Comment: 1st fix your PHP system errors : 'Unable to load dynamic library .. apc' after that you can ask for other problems :)

Comment: am on it btw, i assume that you'll have a solution if i got my system error done ? please don't show off if you don't have the answer :) thank you

Comment: Its not correct to have PHP system errors and to search for help related to logical problems, because its very possible that they are related to your system issues.

Comment: You could have said this first time :), i solved the cache error for now but still getting the first one, weird!